# Zipcode based shipping rates in percentage

Tags: magento, e-commerce

I want to create various shipping rates based on the customers zipcode. I need to calculate them as a percentage of the total amount.

Is there any extension or configuration method to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know about extensions but this tutorial may help you to get your requirement.

[Setting Up Table Rate Shipping](http://go.magento.com/support/kb/entry/name/setting-up-table-rate-shipping/).

If you are not comfortable with this here are [Extension1](http://webkul.com/blog/magento-shipping-checking/) and [Extension2](http://www.webshopapps.com/row/free/matrixrate-shipping-extension.html)